# Spring boot with a relationship oneToMany, problem double object

Tags: java, spring-boot, duplicates, one-to-many

I have a little problem with my spring boot project. To show you my problem I created a second project. I have two classes with a OneToMany relationship. Both classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test2")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Test2 {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "relation_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Test3> test3 = new ArrayList<>();
    
}
```

And the other

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test3")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Test3 {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id3;

    private String test2;
    
}
```

Actual result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "test3": [
            {
                "id3": 1,
                "test2": "0"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "test3": [
            {
                "id3": 2,
                "test2": "0"
            },
            {
                "id3": 3,
                "test2": "1"
            },
            {
                "id3": 4,
                "test2": "3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "test3": [
            {
                "id3": 2,
                "test2": "0"
            },
            {
                "id3": 3,
                "test2": "1"
            },
            {
                "id3": 4,
                "test2": "3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "test3": [
            {
                "id3": 2,
                "test2": "0"
            },
            {
                "id3": 3,
                "test2": "1"
            },
            {
                "id3": 4,
                "test2": "3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "test3": [
            {
                "id3": 5,
                "test2": "11"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Expected result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "test3": [
            {
                "id3": 1,
                "test2": "0"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "test3": [
            {
                "id3": 2,
                "test2": "0"
            },
            {
                "id3": 3,
                "test2": "1"
            },
            {
                "id3": 4,
                "test2": "3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "test3": [
            {
                "id3": 5,
                "test2": "11"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The problem is if the object Test2 has got n element of Test3 on the list I get N entities of Test2 on my return of API, how can I fix the problem? The controller:

```
public interface TestRepo extends JpaRepository<Test2, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM test2 t2 JOIN test3 t3 ON t2.id = t3.relation_id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Test2> getTest2();
    
}
```

The repository:

```
@RestController
public class TestContro {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestContro.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    TestRepo testRepo;

    @GetMapping("/get")
    ResponseEntity<?> findAllTest() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(testRepo.getTest2(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

---

Edit :

Hello, thank for your answer but when a use

1. Delete `@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)`  and change the query for `@Query("select t2 from Test2 t2 join fetch t2.test3")` I get this error when `nativeQuery = true`  is removed …
   `Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testContro': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'testRepo': Error creating bean with name 'testRepo' defined in com.rpImmo.BackServer.repository.TestRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.rpImmo.BackServer.repository.TestRepo.getTest2(); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.rpImmo.BackServer.repository.TestRepo.getTest2()`
2. And for your second option I can't use that because on the future I need to create one special request and not only a simple select with all the row …

Thanks

Édit 2

I think I had find the problem I will try soon. (The problem come to the request I need to change test2 of table name by the name of the class Java Test2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query will return the cartesian product.

1. You can delete `@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)` and use an hql query `@Query("select t2 from Test2 t2 join fetch t2.test3")` with your repo method `List<Test2> getTest2();`

OR

2. You can keep `@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)`, delete your repo method and use `testRepo.findAll()` instead of `testRepo.getTest2()` in the `findAllTest()` method.

Comment: look at my edit post because I get one error when I change my request by remove nativeQuery = true and I don't find a solution of this problem .. it is the first time I get this issue

Comment: @JérômeMartineau, could you show the sql of the database initialization?

Comment: Sorry it’s ok, thanks for your help. the problem is fix because when i removed « nativeQuery = true » on the @Query was I haven’t change the table name by the class name. now i get no error at compilation and the result is good without duplication of entity